# Count articles that are marked "featured on the index page" in joomla

Tags: php, joomla2.5

I would like to be able to anticipate when the `<jdoc:include type="component" />` is not returning any content.

Something like this:

```
<?php if( count(<jdoc:include type="component" />)>=1 ) : ?> 
 <jdoc:include type="component" />
<?php else :?>
 Sorry No Content
<?php endif ; ?>
```

Searched all over but can't find anything that speaks to this. Sorry if this is remedial.

Answer (score 0):

I have this snippet for testing component load errors ... not sure if might work for you

```
<?php if ($this->getBuffer('message')) : ?>  
 <div class="error">  
<h2> Message </h2>
<jdoc:include type="message" />
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Good luck!